# pdffonts and adobe X disagree whether all fonts are embedded

Tags: fonts, pdftex, lyx

I'm finishing up my dissertation (in LyX, converted to pdf with pdflatex), and I checked to ensure that all fonts were embedded in the final pdf file, using pdffonts. It showed that all fonts were embedded.  However, when I take the very same pdf file and open it with Adobe Reader X version 10.1.4 on a Windows machine, it shows a bunch of Type 3 fonts that are not embedded (neither "(embedded)" nor "(embedded subset)" appears next to their name).

What the heck?!?!  Who is lying?  Adobe Reader, or pdffonts?  Or am I misinterpreting either?

```
pdffonts dissertation_etd.pdf 


name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no     482  0
XUWZCB+CMR10                         Type 1            yes yes no     488  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no     531  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no     532  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no     533  0
IJCTHR+CMSY10                        Type 1            yes yes no     590  0
WSFGOP+CMMI10                        Type 1            yes yes no     591  0
NAEIGF+CMMI7                         Type 1            yes yes no     592  0
FROZOC+CMBX10                        Type 1            yes yes no     593  0
KXPRHG+CMEX10                        Type 1            yes yes no     594  0
TPRWIL+CMSY7                         Type 1            yes yes no     595  0
OGKSEF+CMR7                          Type 1            yes yes no     596  0
NANTFZ+MSBM10                        Type 1            yes yes no     597  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no     660  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no     666  0
TMHVPV+MSAM10                        Type 1            yes yes no     667  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no     680  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no     766  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no     784  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no     786  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no     850  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no     851  0
JWIOXB+Helvetica                     Type 1C           yes yes no     856  0
KPSHBO+TT52D0o00                     Type 1C           yes yes no     857  0
KPSHBO+TT52CFo00                     Type 1C           yes yes no     858  0
NHCAHM+CMMI5                         Type 1            yes yes no     892  0
NOPBSI+CMSY5                         Type 1            yes yes no     893  0
KGCVSC+CMR5                          Type 1            yes yes no     894  0
EGSJXT+Times-Roman                   Type 1C           yes yes no     933  0
IAWSAZ+Symbol                        Type 1C           yes yes no     934  0
WNMMHQ+Helvetica                     Type 1C           yes yes no     935  0
CQYSUU+Times-Italic                  Type 1C           yes yes no     936  0
ITGCUR+MSBM7                         Type 1            yes yes no     957  0
NFSINM+MSAM7                         Type 1            yes yes no     959  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no     969  0
BTUXYB+Times-Roman                   Type 1C           yes yes no     980  0
KPSHBO+TT157BFo00                    Type 1C           yes yes no     999  0
QEHNHK+TT157BCo00                    Type 1C           yes yes yes   1000  0
SYGAIY+Symbol                        Type 1C           yes yes no    1001  0
IEBOJP+Times-Roman                   Type 1C           yes yes no    1002  0
ZKXARV+CMR9                          Type 1            yes yes no    1024  0
KNZWIR+CMSY9                         Type 1            yes yes no    1025  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no    1099  0
EDKWPE+Helvetica                     Type 1C           yes yes no    1103  0
HCOJSC+Helvetica                     Type 1C           yes yes no    1110  0
FUQGVM+Helvetica                     Type 1C           yes yes no    1117  0
QJWPHY+Helvetica                     Type 1C           yes yes no    1130  0
JPOSGK+Helvetica                     Type 1C           yes yes no    1137  0
NUEDLC+Helvetica                     Type 1C           yes yes no    1144  0
AAOWGK+CMBX7                         Type 1            yes yes no    1298  0
BXEXLR+CMMI9                         Type 1            yes yes no    1409  0
RENBRO+CMR6                          Type 1            yes yes no    1410  0
[none]                               Type 3            yes no  no    1411  0
EFGUHB+CMMI6                         Type 1            yes yes no    1416  0
ZJYOPT+esint10                       Type 1            yes yes no    1486  0
ZMVOSH+CMEX9                         Type 1            yes yes no    1771  0
PAAUUR+CMMI8                         Type 1            yes yes no    1805  0
ITLAUF+CMR8                          Type 1            yes yes no    1821  0
HBIEHQ+CMSY6                         Type 1            yes yes no    2214  0
COVVAL+CMEX8                         Type 1            yes yes no    2215  0
TMCDBM+CMSY8                         Type 1            yes yes no    2216  0
```

Comment: Type3 fonts are normally bitmap fonts. There are embedded like every bitmap graphics is embedded. But they don't scale and you will have problems with copy&paste. Check the log-file: At the end is the list of fonts. Are there fonts with the ending `.pk`?

Comment: @Ulrike: There's several fonts like this, which I imagine (?) are 600dpi versions of a .pk font: `<~/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecti0900.600pk>`.  Does the presence of these lines in the log file imply that the font is in fact embedded?

Comment: Install the cm-super fonts to replace this bitmap fonts by type 1 fonts.

Comment: @Ulrike: thanks!  that fixes my immediate problem.  All of those type3 fonts are now type1 fonts.  I still am interested, though, to know why pdffonts reported that those type3 fonts were embedded when they were not (according to Adobe Reader)

Comment: The `pdffont` listing provided shows lots of Type 3 fonts: as such I think as it stands the question is pretty unclear!